# IP geolocating query too slow

Tags: postgresql, ip-address, postgresql-9.3, maxmind

I've recently started using PostgreSQL at work & I'm trying to optimize a query to geolocate users based on their IP address. I'm not entirely sure how to read the output from explain analyze. All tables have been vacuumed since last update, so I know that is not a cause for slowness.

I have the following tables:

**session_ipaddress:**
stores visitors' IP address, and it has ~ 250,000 rows. The relevant columns & indices:

```
session_id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
ip_address INET,
ip_int BIGINT

BTREE INDEX on ip_int
```

**ipblocks_201601:**
MaxMind GeoLite2 City Blocks database obtained from http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/ with two additional columns `min_ip` & `max_ip` that together hold the range of IP addresses in a CIDR block. The relevant columns and indices are:

```
network CIDR PRIMARY KEY,
geoname_id INTEGER,
min_ip BIGINT,
max_ip BIGINT

BTREE INDEX ON geoname_id
BTREE INDEX ON min_ip
BTREE INDEX ON max_ip
```

**ipgeolookup_201601:**
GeoLite2 Location Database for the `en` locale. The relevant columns & indices:

```
geoname_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
country_name VARCHAR,
subdivision_1_name VARCHAR,
city_name VARCHAR

BTREE INDEX ON country_name
BTREE INDEX ON subdivision_1_name
BTREE INDEX ON city_name
```

Here's the query I am running, and it takes ~ 20s to complete.

```
SELECT
  geo.country_name
, geo.subdivision_1_name region_name
, geo.city_name
, COUNT(s.session_id) location_unresolved
FROM session_ipaddress s
JOIN ipblocks_201601 ip ON ip.min_ip <= s.ip_int AND ip.max_ip >= s.ip_int
JOIN ipgeolookup_201601 geo ON geo.geoname_id = ip.geoname_id
WHERE geo.country_name = 'United States' OR geo.country_name = 'Canada'
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Total runtime: 22192.814 ms & this is the output from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`: http://explain.depesz.com/s/DNcV

Comment: Are you sure your `explain analyze` match this query? because there is a sort by `contry_name` and your query doesnt have that sort.

Comment: yes, I'm sure that the explain analyze is for this query. I'm not sure why it needs to sort, I assume it has something to do with the aggregation. Its also sorting on `city_name` & `subdivision_1_name` fields.

Comment: Why the min/max ip? Can't you just do `network >> ip_address`?

Comment: the `network >> ip_address` was even slower & not using indexes. not sure why, but extracting the range into separate columns and converting to integer sped things up to the current level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try add composite index.

one for `ipblocks_201601` to include `(geoname_id, min_ip, max_ip)`

another for `ipgeolookup_201601` to include `(country_name, geoname_id)`

**edit by OP:**

The biggest source of improvement was increasing work_mem from default 1MB to 4MB. The database is on a machine with 2GB Memory.
Execution dropped from 20s to 5s

Adding composite indexes further dropped the execution time another second.

Comment: The biggest improvement came from increasing `work_mem` from 1MB to 4MB (query time ~ 5 sec). Following that, compound indexes on `(country_name, geoname_id)` & `(min_ip, max_ip)` decreased the query time to ~ 4 sec. Interestingly, I tried the query with a compound index on `(geoname_id, min_ip, max_ip)` which did not improve performance, but this index's creation time was much higher than for `(min_ip, max_ip)`

Comment: Well i tought in `work_mem`, because in the explain you can see the sort is perfom in disk instead of memory. The problem is `work_mem` is per operation so if you have many connection open you can over load the server. Maybe you should read this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27893/increasing-work-mem-and-shared-buffers-on-postgres-9-2-significantly-slows-down

Comment: Thanks! This is what I've implemented: Client executes `set local work_mem='4MB';` before running the query, and then committing right after. So, other connections will get the default `1MB work_mem`.

Comment: can you share new explain?